# Rails 2.3: Product has_many Variants - how to do find on Product with conditions on Variant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

This looks like not so rare problem, but yet I couldn't find a good solution. General info:

- Product that has_many Variants
- product.variants are also needed, so they are included

When I have conditions on the Product itself, I do (named_scopes are used normally, but this is not needed to illustrate the problem):

```
Product.all(:conditions => {...}, :include => :variants)
```

I cannot find out what's the best way to search only for Products that have variants which match conditions and include only those. My last idea was:

```
Variant.all(:conditions => {...}, :include => :product).group_by(&:product)
```

But this is not very convenient and does not look like a nice ruby style.
Instead of:

```
@products.each do |p|
 do_stuff_with(p)
 do_other_stuff_with(p.variants)
end
```

I'd have to do

```
@products.each do |p|
 do_stuff_with(p[0])
 do_other_stuff_with(p[1])
end
```

And check which variable do I have or transform the first one to make it look the same as the second - messy... Is there a better solution? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a clause to conditions and do this:

```
Product.all(:conditions => "variants.id is not null", :include => :variants)
```

Comment: my conditions are complicated and I had to use some more tricks, but this clue helped me a lot! thanks